# Sound error on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I have a Acer Aspire One Happy2 Netbook and I am facing two problems when using Windows XP.

When I boot to Windows XP SP3 Pro, I don't hear anything from my netbook after resuming from stand by or hibernate.

When I plug in a headset, the sound comes from both the headset and the built-in netbook's speaker, but everything is working fine when I boot to Ubuntu 11.04 (both two problems don't occur).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and reinstall the [driver](http://www.netbookfiles.com/14436/acer-aspire-one-happy-2-audio-driver-win7-6016307/) for your audio

Comment: I've tried reinstall my Windows more than twice. But, I'm still stuck with these problems up till now.